# Kendo DataSource filter parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, model-binding, kendo-datasource

We are trying to use [Kendo DataSource](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource) object to create requests to our custom `ActionResult`.

The `ActionResult` receives the same type of parameters as `KendoGrid` is sending.

We don't want to use `KendoGrid` to display the data, we just need the filtering functionality of `KendoDataSource`.

[image]

```
public ActionResult Search([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var dbItems = _db.DataItems.ToDataSourceResult(request).Data;
    return Json(dbItems, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    serverSorting: true,
    sort: { field: "DataItemName", dir: "desc" },
    transport: {
        read: {
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/Search"
        }
    },
});
dataSource.read();
```

What are we doing wrong?

PS: Setting the method to `POST` makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

Changing the DataSource configuration to this it worked:

Also the `ActionResult` is of type `POST`

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    serverSorting: true,
    serverFiltering: true,
    serverGrouping: true,
    serverPaging: true,
    type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
    sort: { field: "DataItemName", dir: "desc" },
    transport: {
        read: {
            prefix: "",
            url: "/Home/Search"
        }
    },
});
```